# Run code repeatedly when a certain form is visible

Tags: c#, animation, picturebox

I want to run a certain method every x milliseconds when a form is visible (so as to change the contents of a picturebox within that form, so that an animation is displayed, to be precise) without obviously blocking events. I cannot load a .gif since I will be using spritesheets and atlas files. I believe this approach steps outside of the event-driven programming language paradigm that comes with .net/c#. I am not sure of the correct way to face this problem - maybe using a thread, but that sounds a bit overkill - any suggestions?

Comment: *"I believe this approach steps outside of the event-driven programming language paradigm that comes with .net/c#"* Not at all, especially given the use of a Timer that has a callback event. Depending on what the X is in milliseconds, you may have a choppy animation though since timers are not precision events (prempted by other OS tasks and threads).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a timer which will fire an event at regular intervals. As to only doing that while the form is visible, you can disable the timer when the form is minimized or hidden, and re-enable it when it's shown again.